# MySQL Connection Error in Python

Tags: python, mysql, connector

I want to connect to mysql server. The SQL server is installed with XAMPP. I want to write a script for streamlabs chatbot but stuck at this point.

I'm not able to connect to the MySQL Server. I get the following Debug Error:

> FileName: C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py
>   Function recv_plain
>  LineNr: 244
>  Message: unsupported operand
>   type(s) for +=:'bytearray' and 'str'

So it's a problem in the connector library.

```
MysqlDB = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='xxx', host='127.0.0.1', database='stream')
```

I can start the script outside of streamlabs and it connects as intended. I can make select queries and so on. Is there someone who can give me a clue?